# Contain Content within Bootstrap Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a container that takes up 100% width of the screen. The problem is I have been unable to make the content fit within the Bootstrap thumbnail. This problem gets even worse when I shrink the viewport down.

How would I change my code to make it be more responsive.

Check out the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvL7bqfz/1/

```
<div id='thumbnailDiv' class="thumbnail">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<img src='http://placehold.it/350x150' class="thumbnailImg">
</div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h4> Awesome Post Title  </h4>
            <br>
            <h4> Awesome Post Description  </h4>


            <p>
                <a class = "btn btn-primary" > More Info </a>
            </p>
            </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#thumbnailDiv{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.thumbnailImg {
    float: left;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 230px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `col-sm-4` for the thumbnail container and `col-sm-8` for the extra info? Then when the viewport goes less than 768px it will stack them on top of each other.

And set the img to `width: 100%;` but restrict it with `max-width: 350px` (or whatever your actual img width is).

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2gctwb3r/